# Row added using insertNewObject from another class does not show up in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a ViewController (CreateRowController) that has a textfield for a string, which is then given to MasterViewController to create a row. But there is no new row added. I thought it is something to do with the table view updates, so I tried to do reloadData() in place of beginUpdates() and endUpdates(), but that didn't solve it. I also tried different tableView.insertRows, but it didn't change anything.

MasterViewController:

```
import UIKit

var className: String!

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = [] as Array

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(createNewRow(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.isCollapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

@objc
func createNewRow (_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createRowController") as! CreateRowController
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func insertNewObject (_sender: Any) {
    print(className!)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    objects.append(className!) //can change className
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: objects.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! String
            let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}


}
```

CreateViewController:

```
import UIKit

class CreateRowController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var nameOfEvent: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfClasses: UITextField!

var name = ""
var numClasses = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func create(_ sender: Any) {
    self.name = nameOfEvent.text!
    self.numClasses = Int(numberOfClasses.text!)!
    className = self.name
    MasterViewController().insertNewObject(_sender: self)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "createdRowToList", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.destination is MasterViewController {
        className = self.name
    }

}

}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Sorry, I'm fairly new to xcode.

Edit: I tried vadian's answer, so look at the comment on his answer if you need more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the error in MasterViewController. The line `var objects = [] as Array` in the first bit apparently resets the array when I go into that scene, so I just moved it out of the class and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a very common mistake. `MasterViewController()` creates a new instance of the controller which is not the instance in the storyboard.

Delete the line

```
MasterViewController().insertNewObject(_sender: self)
```

and in `prepare(for` get the proper instance of `MasterViewController`, assign the name to `className` and call insertNewObject

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let masterController = segue.destination as? MasterViewController {
        masterController.className = self.name
        masterController.insertNewObject(nil)
    }
}
```

---

However I would declare `insertNewObject` to pass the name as parameter (`begin/endUpdates` is pointless in this context)

```
func insertNewObject(name: String) {
    objects.append(name)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: objects.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

and change `prepare(for` to

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let masterController = segue.destination as? MasterViewController {
        masterController.insertNewObject(self.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I tried this and it doesn't seem to work, the table is blank after trying to add. I put print(objects) after the append, and it does print the list, so I think it may have something to do with not properly inserting the row? Any more advice?

Comment: Also, I realized that when i do print(objects), after trying to add another thing to objects, it replaces the original one rather than appending.

Comment: In the code there is no evidence that the object is replaced.

Comment: Yes, so I don't know why it happens. And the row doesn't show up in the table view.